# onClick="window.location='/viewAllAdmins';" is submitting form instead of forwarding to provided link

Tags: html, css

```
<table border=0 align=center cellpadding=9>
<tr>
<td>
<button class="font-awesome-btn" onClick="window.location='/viewAllAdmins';"  style="margin:auto; display:block;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Go Back  </button>
</td>
<td>
<button class="font-awesome-btn"> Submit <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</td>
</tr></table>
```

onClick event submitting form instead of bringing me to the provided URL.

Comment: That’s because your button is a _submit_ button, and you did not suppress its default action. You could set `type="button"` to simply work around that. But using a button is rather an “abuse” of that element in the first place here - if you simply want to _link to_ somewhere else - then you should _use_ a link, `<a>`. Format it to _look like_ a button via CSS, if desired.

Comment: @CBroe please answer my question to mark as correct. It works

Answer (score 2):

That’s because your button is a submit button, and you did not suppress its default action. You could set `type="button"` to simply work around that.

---

But using a button is rather an “abuse” of that element in the first place here - if you simply want to *link to* somewhere else - then you should *use* a link, `<a>`. Format it to *look like* a button via CSS, if desired.